# How to reconstruct a local variable environment in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, eval

I'm reformatting a bunch of data processing code. The original code first declare several functions, they have certain topological dependency(which means some function rely on other function's result), then calling them sequentially(using a correct topo sort):

```
def func_1(df):
    return df.apply(...)

def func_2(df):
    return pd.concat([df, ...])

def func_3(df_1, df_2):
    return pd.merge(df_1, df_2)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    df=...
    df_1 = func_1(df)
    df_2 = func_2(df)
    result = func_3(df_1, df_2)# the func_3 rely on the result of func_1 & func_2
```

The problem is that I'm not able to retrieve intermediate data. Say I just want to apply func_1 & func_2, I need to change some code. And it gets complicated when topological dependency gets complicated.

So I want to change into kind of like makefiles's recursive recipe:

```
def recipe_1(df):
    return df.apply(...)

def recipe_2(df):
    return pd.concat([df, ...])

def recipe_3(df):
    df_1 = recipe_1(df)
    df_2 = recipe_2(df)
    #some process here.
    return 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    df = ...
    recipe_3(df) #Just call the intermediate node I need.
```

The problem of this approach is I need to collect a lot of variable from `recipe_1`and`recipe_2` in `recipe_3`, so I think it would be nice if I am able to retrieve the variables from `locals()`, which will leave the other code in `#some process here.` unchanged.

Now I'm thinking something like this but it looks ugly:

```
def func_to_be_reconstructed():
    a = 3
    return locals()

local_variables = func_to_be_reconstructed()
for key in local_variables.keys():
    exec(str(key) + '= local_variables[\'' + str(key) + '\']')
```

better solution?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? What would be your use case for this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I create variable variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-variable-variables) TL;DR - don't use `exec` to create new variables, just use `loacals()` as a dict...

Comment: This really doesn't make a lot of sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`globals()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#globals) and [`locals()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#locals) are just dicts...

So, instead of using `exec` in such a fishy way, just [`update`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.update) the dict:

```py
def func_to_be_reconstructed():
    a = 3
    return locals()

globals().update(func_to_be_reconstructed())
```

Comment: So if I want to use them in another function, I can use locals().update(func_to_be_reconstructed()) in that function?

Comment: Yes, although I'm pretty sure a better way to do this is just `return` the values you need from the function and re-use them elsewhere...

Answer (score 0):

**This is probably bad practice but** you could use the `global` keyword on variables you wish to refer to outside the function.

```
def func_to_be_reconstructed():
    global a
    a = 3

print(a)
```

This is especially useful if you just need several variables. Take a look at this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3089208/overwrite-global-var-in-one-line-in-python).

**EDIT**: A single global list can be filled with multiple variables:

```
def write_to_msv(*vars):
    global my_special_var
    my_special_var = []
    for k in vars:
        my_special_var.append(k)

myvar1 = 123
myvar2 = "hello"
myvar3 = {'no shoes': 'no service'}

write_to_msv(myvar1, myvar2, myvar3)

print(my_special_var)
```

Again: ["You can use global variables but you shouldn't"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55637679/how-to-move-multiple-variables-from-a-function-into-the-global-scope#comment97966576_55637679)

Comment: What if they have 10 variables? What if there are 50?

Comment: In that case I'd probably have the function return all the variables in a list or some kind of container. Check the edit above, the described method be applicable.

Answer (score 0):

This looks a bit cleaner but does mostly the same.

```
for var,value in func_to_be_reconstructed().items(): f"{var} = {value}")
```